# Asp.Net - Internet Explorer 10 - Javascript removed from page unless in Compatibility Mode

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-10

I have a website built using Visual Studio 2010 (may have been upgraded), running with .Net 3.5 SP1 in Dev and on the Web Server.

When I go to my Login page, in development or on my test server, I can login just fine.  The login page depends on a few pieces of auto generated JavaScript code I can only assume are created at runtime by Asp.Net.

One being a JavaScript method called `__doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument)`.

When I go to my Login page on my Production Server, the login page doesn't work any more.  What I've found is that all of the JavaScript I have in the page Is suddenly gone.

I am also missing a lot of ASP generated hidden input elements.  Like,

```
__LASTFOCUS
__EVENTTARGET
__EVENTARGUMENT
__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR
```

Now if I enable Compatibility Mode, it all comes right back and works just fine.  View Source show's my JavaScript is back and the missing ASP generated input elements are back as well.

Anyone ever seen this?

I did read the article about this being a common issue due to ASP.Net not recognizing IE 10 as a valid browser.  [Bug and Fix: ASP.Net fails to detect IE10 causing _doPostBack....](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx) is the article I'm referring to.

I find it strange that the KB's this article points to show much later time stamps on the ie.browser files than what I have on my development machine.  My machine shows my ie.browser file was created and last modified in 2009.  However the KB's show that if I have a good ie.browser file, the timestamp should be Aug 31 2011.  So I don't really know why I'm not having this problem on my development machine.

Comment: It sure sounds like ASP.Net is serving "downlevel" content. Have you applied the KB fix to a staging environment similar to production? (or production, if you are able to potentially disrupt service)

Comment: Nope.  I didn't know this was an issue until we upgraded from IE 8 to IE 10.  Suddenly the issue pops up on the Production server and the Test Server as well as my local machine is working fine.